# Is there a way to make a custom loadstring() function in lua?

Tags: lua

Here is an example

**local CustomLoad = function(l) loadstring(l) end**

**CustomLoad("print('hi')")**

Please let me know, beacuse I got into this like a week ago, and I've been trying to make it, yet I coudln't. Can some of you tell me if it's even possible?

Comment: Do you have standard `loadstring` available?  What is the desired difference between standard and custom functions?  Do you need to load (convert string to a function but don't run it) or execute (load and run this function)?

Comment: May be you whant to the load function with the custom data reader?

Comment: I was wondering if I can make a custom loadstring that requires a key while executing the code, for example: if loadstring has data and 123 (the key), then it would allow the execution.

Comment: https://github.com/moteus/lua-AesFileEncrypt/blob/master/examples/eload.lua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't trying to run "print('hi')" in that example, then I do believe you're missing a return statement.

```
local CustomLoad = function(l) return loadstring(l) end
```

But if you are, then:

```
local CustomLoad = function(l) return loadstring(l) end
CustomLoad("print('hi')")()
```

or

```
local CustomLoad = function(l) local f = loadstring(l); f() end
CustomLoad("print('hi')")
```

Because loadstring creates a function, which, when run, executes the code in the string.
Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks, it will help me alot.